# Is there a similar function to boost::filesystem::remove_all(path) in glib or libc?

Tags: c, linux, glibc, glib, libc

I cannot use boost, but only glib and libc functions.

If you check glib you will find g_remove, g_rmdir, and g_unlink and none of them delete non-empty directories.

I have seen posts that implement a function to recursively delete all files and subdirectories inside a directory like the Linux command "rm -rf path".

I prefer to uses a well tested implementation in C.

Which implementation/api do you recommend ?

thanks.

Comment: Can you use functions from GIO as well as GLib?

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing currently in GIO which implements the equivalent of `rm -rf`, but you can build something which does that fairly easily:

```
/* Recursively delete @file and its children. @file may be a file or a directory. */
static gboolean
rm_rf (GFile         *file,
       GCancellable  *cancellable,
       GError       **error)
{
  g_autoptr(GFileEnumerator) enumerator = NULL;

  enumerator = g_file_enumerate_children (file, G_FILE_ATTRIBUTE_STANDARD_NAME,
                                          G_FILE_QUERY_INFO_NOFOLLOW_SYMLINKS,
                                          cancellable, NULL);

  while (enumerator != NULL)
    {
      GFile *child;

      if (!g_file_enumerator_iterate (enumerator, NULL, &child, cancellable, error))
        return FALSE;
      if (child == NULL)
        break;
      if (!rm_rf (child, cancellable, error))
        return FALSE;
    }

  return g_file_delete (file, cancellable, error);
}
```

Note that the use of [`g_autoptr()`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Miscellaneous-Macros.html#g-autoptr) requires GLib 2.44 and a compiler which supports automatic cleanup (currently, only GCC or Clang). [`g_file_enumerator_iterate()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GFileEnumerator.html#g-file-enumerator-iterate) also requires GLib 2.44.

Comment: +1; maybe I would have mentioned that `g_autoptr` and `g_file_enumerator_iterate` are rather new "phenomenons", but I found this a surprisingly elegant solution.

Comment: I’ve edited it to clarify this. They only require GLib 2.44, which is now quite old (we’ve just released GLib 2.56), but it’s worth pointing out that g_autoptr() only works on GCC or Clang.